# Pycharm doesn't show error information for `PyQt5` program (e.g. `TypeError`)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In Pycharm 4.5.2, if I had an error in `PyQt5` slots, when the slots was called, Pycharm only shows `Process finished with exit code 1`, but not where and why the error happends. This doesn't happen when the error is in `__init__`.
It makes it very difficult to debug. How do I fix this?

This widget is generated by Qt Designer

[image]

For example, if I wrote `button.setText('a'+1)` when clicked on the button:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt
from test import Ui_Form

Application = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

class myWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__()
        self.main = Ui_Form()
        self.main.setupUi(self)
        # self.main.pushButton.setText('a'+1)
        # prints `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly ` normally

        self.show()

        self.main.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_error)

    def show_error(self):
        self.main.pushButton.setText('a'+1)
        # only print "Process finished with exit code 1" when clicked on the button, and crash.


my_Qt_Program = myWidget()
my_Qt_Program.show()
sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

[image]

It works fine in windows console:

[image]

test.py(generated by Qt Designer):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(115, 58)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Show \'a\' +1"))
```

Comment: I am currently facing this problem, too. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I found [this pycharm support thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000176210-Print-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1), which suggests setting the "Emulate terminal in output console" option might show a proper python traceback instead of the useless exit code message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt: No error msg (traceback) on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736819/pyqt-no-error-msg-traceback-on-exit)

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out in the comments and indeed suggested on this [pycharm thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000176210/comments/115000225664):

In your run configuration, enable the option `Emulate terminal in output console`. You can find this in the Execution section.

#### Running your example

On my machine (Windows 10, PyCharm Professional 2018.3.1) this changed the behaviour when clicking the `show 'a' + 1` button from exiting with exit code (`-1073740791 (0xC0000409)`) to showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file/so.py", line 25, in show_error
    self.main.pushButton.setText('a' + 1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

In order to run your example I had to change

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
```

into

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
```

and change the `Qt.Q...` calls into `Q...` accordingly, but this might depend on my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly what you want but this works for me:

```
import logging

def main():
    x = 1/0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')
    main()
```

Edit: The above mention method works if you got a single file but it doesnt fix the root of the problem
A better anwser can be found here [PyQt: No error msg (traceback) on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736819/pyqt-no-error-msg-traceback-on-exit)