# pathos cpickle error on python 2.7.13/14 using windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, multiprocess, dill, pathos

Based on the example [multiprocess using pathos and dill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking) I hit the wall of cPickle errors. I did as [www3cam](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/121) did; with a little addition.. by removing pathos, dill, multiprocess and pyreadline. Then hit `pip install pathos --no-cache-dir` after carefully removed those side-packages mentioned above. Fresh install, cold-reboot of PC and an Anacoda2 update later... the jar with cPickles... is still there and Frank Zappa keeps singing his "Titties and Beer" song.

The modified code from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import datetime, time
import multiprocessing
import pathos.pools as pp
import dill


class Multiprocess(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def qmp_worker(self,(inputs, the_time)):
        print " Processs %s\tWaiting %s seconds" % (inputs, the_time)
        time.sleep(int(the_time))
        print " Process %s\tDONE" % inputs

    def qmp_handler(self):                           # Non tandem pair processing
        pool = pp.ProcessPool(2)
        pool.map(self.qmp_worker, data)

def mp_worker((inputs, the_time)):
    print " Process %s\tWaiting %s seconds" % (inputs, the_time)
    time.sleep(int(the_time))
    print " Process %s\tDONE" % inputs
    sys.stdout.flush()

def mp_handler():                           # Non tandem pair processing
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(mp_worker, data)

def mp_handler_tandem():
    subdata = zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])
#    print subdata
    for task1, task2 in subdata:
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
        p.map(mp_worker, (task1, task2))

#data = (['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['d', '4'])
data = (['a', '2'], ['b', '3'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '4'], 
        ['e', '1'], ['f', '2'], ['g', '3'], ['h', '4'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout.flush()
#    print 'mp_handler():'
#    mp_handler()
#    print '---'
#    time.sleep(2)

#    print '\nmp_handler_tandem():'
#    mp_handler_tandem()
    print '---'
#    time.sleep(2)

    Multiprocess().qmp_handler()
```

Perhaps something should be set like with the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039363) "catching and printing PyQt5 tracebacks?

Snippet code below that made me thinking and curious if something like that has to be done done for dill?

```
# Back up the reference to the exceptionhook
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

# Set the exception hook to our wrapping function
sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook
```

Latest error:

> File "c:\python\anac2\lib\site-packages\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 137, in map
>      return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
>    File "c:\python\anac2\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
>      return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
>    File "c:\python\anac2\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
>      raise self._value
>   cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.function failed

More info about this error is at: [my cPickle dump](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/125).