# Segmentation fault: 11 on a QMainWindow exit button with pyqt5 on OSX

Tags: python, pyqt

I get a strange behavior that's happening on OSX but not on Windows.

I made a software with pyqt5 and when I close a child window I have a crash with  "Segmentation fault: 11"

To explain better, I have a main window where I may open other windows to ask to the user some info. the error is happening when I close that second window.

I have a `closeEvent` function :

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.Close_OBJ.emit()
    self.close()
```

which send a `pyqtSignal`to the main window.

If I comment the `self.Close_OBJ.emit()`I don't have the Segmentation fault anymore, but I need this so my main window can react to the closing of that child window.

What is also confusing is that I have other child windows where I have the same `closeEvent` function and it's work well.
I don't understand why I don't have this issue on Windows OS.

Here's a minimal example of the issue:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Modify_1_NMM(QMainWindow):
    Close_OBJ = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Modify_1_NMM, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel('Please, close this window')
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.label)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.Close_OBJ.emit()
        self.close()


class StimEdit(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StimEdit, self).__init__()
        self.NewModifyXNMM = None
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()

        self.B = QPushButton('clik here to open o window')
        self.B.setFixedSize(400,200)
        self.B.clicked.connect(self.ModXNMMclicked)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.B)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)


    def ModXNMMclicked(self,):
        if self.NewModifyXNMM  == None:
            self.NewModifyXNMM = Modify_1_NMM()
            self.NewModifyXNMM.Close_OBJ.connect(self.close_ModXNMM)
            self.NewModifyXNMM.show()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def close_ModXNMM(self):
        print('about to close',self)
        self.NewModifyXNMM = None
        print('did closed')



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StimEdit(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I click on the button on the main window, a second window opens. When I then close the second window, it crashes (not even all the time... but most of the time).

On pycharm I get this error message :

```
about to close <__main__.StimEdit object at 0x103f0af78>
did closed
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

and on the terminal I get:

```
about to close <__main__.StimEdit object at 0x10c706288>
did closed
Segmentation fault: 11
```

### UPDATE

if I comment out the line `self.NewModifyXNMM = None` I don't have the segmentation fault anymore. Is it possible this line is in conflict with the window closing?

Comment: try changing `self.close()` to `super().closeEvent(event)`

Comment: Same error with `super()closeEvent(event)`

Comment: You can provide an MCVE, maybe the error is caused by some other configuration

Comment: I just did, you're rigth I should add the example earlier...

Comment: Try the following answer to see if you get an error message, execute it in the terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47275100/6622587

Comment: I didn't have any message with the code in the link

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pyqt5? Are you using pip for the installation? I recommend you report the bug

Comment: Yes I think I have (PyQt version: 5.12.1) and I did install it with pip. Where do you suggest I may report this issue?

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug

Comment: try delete `self.close()`

Comment: deleting `self.close()` didn't help. Maybe it is coming from my version of OSX (10.14.2) which is not compatible with all pyqt stuff yet. I will try tomorrow on another mac to see if the same error appears. At least, this works on Windows (as a small compensation :)

Comment: In Linux it also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the object reference is being lost when you set a None to the variable, a possible workaround is to use deleteLater and the destroyed signal:

```py
@pyqtSlot()
def close_ModXNMM(self):
    print('about to close',self)
    self.NewModifyXNMM.deleteLater()
    self.NewModifyXNMM.destroyed.connect(self.on_destroyed)
    print('did closed')

@pyqtSlot('QObject*')
def on_destroyed(self, o):
    self.NewModifyXNMM = None
    print(self.NewModifyXNMM)
```

Comment: I do not understand why it was working on windows but not on OSX though.

Comment: @ymmx Maybe an internal implementation makes it work differently in each OS