# maya.cmds Dialog to end script

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I would like to end an entire script once an attribute has not been found. Currently, I have the following code. I display a dialog and use `sys.exit()` to end the script but I m wondering if there is a cmds dialog that does this automatically for you without `sys.exit()`,

```
def check_attr(attr):
    if not cmds.select(cmds.ls(attr)):
         cmds.confirmDialog(title= 'Attribute not found   ', message = attr+' attribute was not found', button =['OK'])
         sys.exit()
```

My question: **Does a cmds...Dialog that stops a script exist?**

Comment: do you mean like something as : cmds.error() ? And there is no dialog preset for error but you can wrap yours.

Comment: also you can use PySide2 or PyQt5 in maya so you could use QMessageBox : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227047/python-pyqt5-how-to-show-an-error-message-with-pyqt5

Comment: @DrWeeny I mean something like cmds.exitDialog("error message ") and it just exits but I m thinking that dialogs don't have that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a function the easiest way would be to use `return` in your `if` condition so that it never continues the rest of the function:

```
def check_attr(attr):
    if not cmds.select(cmds.ls(attr)):
         cmds.confirmDialog(title= 'Attribute not found   ', message = attr+' attribute was not found', button =['OK'])
         return

    print "Continuing script"


check_attr("someAttr")
```

You can also use `OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError` to display it in Maya's taskbar:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


def check_attr(attr):
    if not cmds.select(cmds.ls(attr)):
         OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError(attr + ' attribute was not found')
         return

    print "Continuing script"


check_attr("attr")
```

Though be careful since `OpenMaya.MGlobal.displayError` simply *displays* an error, it doesn't stop execution like `cmds.error`. You could use `cmds.error` too, but I find that the error it spits out in the taskbar is a lot less readable.