# How to catch PyQt5 exception? "Process finished with exit code"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Question:
How do I get an error message, if something does wrong in PyQt5 and my program crashes with the PyCharm console message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

As I noticed this error can happen for different reasons but it is very hard to understand where the problem causes if no error stack trace

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions to add answers. If you find an alternative solution, post your answer to the existing question. It's more helpful to other users if all the potential solutions can be found in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the PyCharm's Settings, search PyQt5, in PyQt compatible change "auto" to "PyQt5", that's all, now you will see the stack trace of the PyQt5 non-catchable errors

[image]

Comment: i had same issue and sorted with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736819/pyqt-no-error-msg-traceback-on-exit. your approach is interesting and wonder why pycharm Auto setting not working