# How can I log PyQt5 sudden crashes?

Tags: python, pyqt5, crash

I'm using PyQt5 as a GUI for my python app.
Sometimes the code crashes with these types of errors:

[image: pyqt5 error Image]

Is there a way to log these types of crashes with explanation (like error exception).

Edit:
found an easy way.
 just run via cli
>> py filename.py
works like magic. (or if using pycharm, debug mode)

Comment: Don't use pycharm, run it in CMD  o console.

Comment: If you're using pycharm, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53729804/984421).

Answer (score 0):

The general method for error catching is this:

```py
try:
    # try something that does not work
    a*5
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

the output would look like this (for the example error):

```
name 'a' is not defined
```

Here is a link:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

However, you might need to do other debugging, logging and printing to terminal to find the error.

Comment: This won't necessarily work in the OP's case.  If Qt gets upset somewhere in its C++ backend, it prints the reason to std error and calls abort, it doesn't go via python exceptions.

Comment: @stevecu,  what would be the approach in respect of a case where the C++ backend was upset as you have pointed out ?

Comment: If you call `QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler`, see for example [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/84022/code-for-qinstallmessagehandler) right at the start of your Qt usage, you can catch fatal/critical errors.  Qt will still raise `abort` but at least you can log the reason first.  However, if you access Qt from the wrong thread, I think it's possible to cause a genuine fault-type crash, in which case this handler won't be called.

Comment: So basically outside of the standard `try-except` statement. This is the next best alternative for any C++ back end...