# PyQt: unknown console messages

Tags: python, qt, error-handling, pyqt

I have a PyQt6 gui application.
If I run it in a command window (I am working on Windows), I get log messages from Py(?)Qt:

```
(venv) PS C:\application> python .\main.py
QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
...
```

If I run it in my IDE (pycharm) I do not see these messages. No exceptions either. I do not see any unintended behaviour in respect to the QTableWidget.

- How can I debug this?
- Who is sending these messages?
- Is there a way to route these messages into the application and the python logger?

Comment: Firstly, make sure your [IDE is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31884991/984421) to show error output. Secondly, the messages are shown by Qt due to bugs in your code. To make them go away, you can fix the bugs in the manner implied by the messages.

Comment: As the error shows, you're probably using `setItem()` with the same item in different tables. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks. The link was helpful to increase visiblilty while working in pycharm. I am still confused why pyqt6 is not raising any exceptions while qt seems to be unhappy with what I am doing.

Comment: @R.Bert an exception is raised when it is potentially critical for the program execution, that is just a warning: Qt is saying that you cannot do that, it will then just ignore that function call, as such a "mistake" shouldn't cause the program to completely crash.

Comment: @musicamante the question was not about resolving the bug but about the signaling. Additionally I was not aware that this can happen. Meaning: Misusing qt without raising exceptions. Thanks anyway. If I need help with the bug I will follow your advice.

Comment: @musicamante I guess you just answered my question. Is this the qt core c code that sends this warning?

Comment: @R.Bert It's simply because Qt never raises exceptions, so there's nothing to re-raise. In general, Qt prefers to use return values to indicate success/failure (where possible), and otherwise outputs warning messages. For critical errors, it will abort execution.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks. I get it. And my practial issue with debugging is solved by the link you provided.

Comment: @R.Bert See also: [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and [qCritical](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qCritical) (+ friends).

Comment: @ekhumoro  do you want to write an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure your [IDE is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31884991/984421) to show error output. Secondly, the messages are shown by Qt due to bugs in your code. To make them go away, you can fix the bugs in the manner implied by the messages.

Qt never raises exceptions as such, so there's nothing to re-raise on the Python side. In general, Qt prefers to use return values to indicate success/failure (where possible), and otherwise outputs warning messages. For critical errors, it will abort execution (see [qCritical](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qCritical) and related functions for the exact circumstances under which this may happen).

To control the output of Qt messages, you can use [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).